# Get E-mail id from twitter OAuth API

Tags: php, authentication, twitter, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I have run into a authentication issue using the `codebird` function for twitter.

I need to get the E-mail from twitter. I have checked the 'request email address' in the permission section of the API settings in twitter.

here is my function that handles the login :

```
public function signIn()
{
    if($this->hasCallback())
    {
        $this->verifyTokens();

        $reply = $this->twitter_client->oauth_accessToken([
            //'include_email' => 'true', //tried this as well without any positive output
            'oauth_verifier' => $_GET['oauth_verifier']
        ]);

        //This one rsponded with an auth failure
        //$reply = $this->twitter_client->account_verifyCredentials
        // ([
        //     'include_entities' => 'true',
        //     'skip_status' => 'true',
        //     'include_email' => 'true',
        //     'oauth_callback' => $this->clientCallback
        //   ]);

        if($reply->httpstatus === 200)
        {
            $this->storeTokens($reply->oauth_token, $reply->oauth_token_secret);

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $reply->user_id;

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try the answer submitted 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797163/how-to-retrieve-twitter-user-email-using-codebird-php)